# Is there one or more solutions to this system of stiff linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

it is a question of hydrodynamics,and i have evaluated all the known Physical quantity，so there are only 6 unknown,

I use the default of the solve function, but it can't get a solution,

```
sol = Solve[{alpha[0] == 
6.9452661266553415` - (2.691307288165229`*^61 - 
    6.1630057357396486`*^60 I) aa[0] + 
 0.0005756591988055512` aa[1] + 1.4836217721967435`*^-8 aa[2], 
alpha[1] == 
6.9452661266553415` + (2.690177977346087`*^61 - 
    6.1604196508706296`*^60 I) aa[0] - 
 0.0005795167180894829` aa[1] - 1.4847619644675353`*^-8 aa[2], 
alpha[2] == 
6.9452661266553415` - (2.6867957242378484`*^61 - 
    6.152674401787605`*^60 I) aa[0] + 
 0.0005914058327383139` aa[1] + 1.488193080699163`*^-8 aa[2], 
aa[0] == (-0.01865295829650781` + 
   0.0947158131902396` I) (-7.853457866365679`*^61 - 
   5.3448365305565616`*^60 alpha[1] + 
   4.105427712466962`*^61 alpha[2]), 
aa[1] == -26.813731172513215` (-0.03198613745886671` - 
   0.0021923914657948863` alpha[1] + 
   0.0172071159126169` alpha[2]), 
aa[2] == -15804.107513690864` (-0.0039269646434191684` - 
   0.00026757553967274273` alpha[1] + 
   0.0020626199050551887` alpha[2])}, {alpha[0], alpha[1], 
alpha[2], aa[0], aa[1], aa[2]}]
```

hints are as this,

```
RowReduce::luc: Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix {{-1.48362*10^-8+0.     I,-0.000575659+0. I,7.39164*10^62+1.07904*10^62 I,0. +0. I,0. +0. I,1. +0. I,-    6.94527+0. I},{1.48476*10^-8+0. I,0.000579517 +0. I,-7.38868*10^62-1.0786*10^62 I,0.     +0. I,1. +0. I,0. +0. I,-6.94527+0. I},<<3>>,{1. +0. I,0. +0. I,0. +0. I,32.5979 +0.     I,-4.22879+0. I,0. +0. I,-62.0622+0. I}} may contain significant numerical errors.


Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know what a [matrix condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) of approximately `5 * 10^61` means?  Where do the coefficients in your equations come from (or how were they computed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rationalize your equations

```
eqn={alpha[0] == 6.9452661266553415` - (2.691307288165229`*^61-6.1630057357396486`*^60 I) aa[0] +0.0005756591988055512` aa[1]+1.4836217721967435`*^-8 aa[2], 
alpha[1] ==6.9452661266553415` + (2.690177977346087`*^61 -6.1604196508706296`*^60 I) aa[0] -0.0005795167180894829` aa[1] -1.4847619644675353`*^-8 aa[2], 
alpha[2] ==6.9452661266553415` - (2.6867957242378484`*^61 -6.152674401787605`*^60 I) aa[0] +0.0005914058327383139` aa[1] +1.488193080699163`*^-8 aa[2], 
aa[0] == (-0.01865295829650781` +0.0947158131902396` I)(-7.853457866365679`*^61 -5.3448365305565616`*^60 alpha[1] + 4.105427712466962`*^61 alpha[2]), 
aa[1] == -26.813731172513215` (-0.03198613745886671` - 0.0021923914657948863`alpha[1] + 0.0172071159126169` alpha[2]),
aa[2] == -15804.107513690864` (-0.0039269646434191684` - 0.00026757553967274273` alpha[1] + 0.0020626199050551887` alpha[2])} //Rationalize[#, 0] &
```

Solve finds a solution without warning.

```
sol = Solve[eqn, {alpha[0], alpha[1], alpha[2], aa[0], aa[1], aa[2]}];
N[sol]
(*{{alpha[0.] -> 3.28707 + 1.03232*10^-16 I,
```

alpha[1.] -> 10.6019 - 5.60127*10^-17 I, 
  alpha[2.] -> 3.2932 - 7.29226*10^-18 I, 
  aa[0.] -> 1.29153*10^-61 + 2.95756*10^-62 I, 
  aa[1.] -> -0.0385272 + 7.17832*10^-20 I, 
  aa[2.] -> -0.455932 + 8.46237*10^-19 I}}*)

Comment: great answer but is there a difference of the solution whether we use Rationalize

Comment: Sure. It is a good advice to calculate symbolicaly as long as possible! Otherwise Mathematica "rounds" your equations before solving!

Comment: ok,thanks a lot!you makes me believe it is a magic place here!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @dcydhb DSolve does not work with inaccurate expressions, therefore type `alpha[0] == 
6.9452661266553415` - (2.691307288165229`*^61 - 
    6.1630057357396486`*^60 I) aa[0] + 
 0.0005756591988055512` aa[1] + 1.4836217721967435`*^-8 aa[2]` expressions are not allowed. To make the expression accurate, use Rationalize